# How to stop an app from running completely on OS X?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

Few days back I installed Team Viewer on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks. It worked fine at the first. Now the app is stuck on the dock saying "Application not responding" and it's running indefinitely.

### What I've tried to stop the app from running

1. Force Quit from Dock
2. Killing from Activity Monitor
3. Tried to restart the mac and the app launched automatically even though it's not set to launch during startup under system preferences.

There are two processes using the CPU which when I try to force quit gets automatically relaunched.

[image]

**How do i stop the app or how do I stop these processes from running ever again?**

Comment: I have version 8.0.16901 and it responds to Force Quit using alt+cmd+Esc!

Comment: I also do NOT have the TeamViewer_Desktop process running. Are you connected to someone ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Nope, I'm not connected to anyone. The app won't load for force quit using  alt+cmd+Esc!

Comment: Can you run the Uninstall TeamViewer ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I wasn't able to uninstall because the app was still running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a launchctl process that is restarting.

To see all loaded launch agents, in Terminal:

```
launchctl list
```

To remove one:

```
sudo launchctl remove label_of_program_to_remove
```

where, **label_of_program_to_remove** is found in the preceding list.  Note that you have to run the sudo command from an administrator account; or, `su` to an administrator account first.

Comment: I found two labels - `com.teamviewer.desktop` and `com.teamviewer.teamviewer`, but when I try to remove it `sh-3.2# launchctl remove com.teamviewer.teamviewer` it says this
`launchctl remove error: No such process`

Comment: I was able to remove it from the list without using sudo.

Comment: Great! Now that that is working, the second (and more permanent) step is to move the com.teamviewer files from either /Library/LaunchAgents/ or your ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ folder.  Instead of removing them outright, you should move them someplace else in case you want to try again.

Comment: Ok, what the heck. I have used launchctl to stop, unload, and remove all the teamviewer processes and it no longer shows up in `launctl list` and I moved all the plist files away, but I *still* get error messages in system.log saying it's trying to run something every 10 seconds and is failing!

Comment: Can you open a new question, and copy the error message as well as the output of "launchctl list" (remove anything that might compromise your privacy, etc)

Comment: My macbook pro sporadically shuts down. The teamviewer I used to have continues running. I did sudo launchctl remove com.teamviewer.teamviewer, but after rebooting the computer it starts again...

Comment: You also need to remove the files from the LaunchAgents folder if you want the change to be permanent. See the comment above that starts with "Great!"

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Teamviewer preferences. Under the general tab unclick "Start TeamViewer with system". Apply and afterwards you should be able to close the program.

Comment: It doesn't work if the Teamviewer is forever not responding

Comment: I installed TeamViewer Host - where is the preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to reinstall TeamViewer. In a a situation where you're unable to uninstall because TeamViwer is currently open (which you can't close) follow the steps below:

1. On TeamViewer Go to Preferences.
2. Select Advanced from the tabs.
3. Scroll down to the bottom and select uninstall.